# Swift: search and randomly select in array (of Parse query results) but give precedence to newer objects?

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, random

I am basically trying to create a basic search algorithm in Swift for objects returned by my Parse query. 
Right now, when a user searches multiple object can match the search term. An array of the matching objects is returned and right now I can randomly select and display one with this:

```
let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(results!.count)))

        let selectedIdea = results![rand]
//then output selectedIdea
```

When I query, I can sort my query results by date using `.orderByAscending("createdAt")`. This all works well.

I need to know whether there is a way to still RANDOMLY select an object from this results array but give PRECEDENCE (so I guess not entirely randomly) to the objects at the front of the array? Meaning there is a highly likelihood of a newly posted object being selected than old?

If this isn't possible, how would one incrementally move through an array of objects (going from first index to last then cycling again) when I have different results arrays being returned each time (the user can search for a different term or the same term).

I don't want to just select the most recent object because this would mean this recent object would likely be selected and displayed multiple multiple times. Is there a way to start with most recent object and as that same results array is returned again, moving to next recent and next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is called *weighted random* where each discrete value is assigned a different probability of being selected. I made a class called `WeightRandomDistribution` for the task:

```
class WeightedRandomDistribution<T> {
    var values: [T]
    var weights: [Double]

    private var totalWeight: Double {
        get {
            return self.weights.reduce(0.0, combine: +)
        }
    }

    init(values: [T], weights: [Double]) {
        guard values.count == weights.count else {
            fatalError("You must assign a weight to every value")
        }

        self.values = values
        self.weights = weights
    }

    func nextRandomValue() -> T {
        let randomValue = Double(arc4random()) / Double(UInt32.max) * self.totalWeight

        var index = 0
        var cummulativeWeight = self.weights[0]
        while cummulativeWeight < randomValue {
            index += 1
            cummulativeWeight += self.weights[index]
        }

        return self.values[index]
    }
}
```

**Usage:** let's say you have an array containing `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and you want it such that 1 appears twice as often as 2; 2 appear twice as often as 3, etc.:

```
let dist = WeightedRandomDistribution(values: Array(1...5), weights: [16, 8, 4, 2, 1])
for _ in 0..<100 {
    let r = dist.nextRandomValue()
    print(r)
}
```

You can copy the result to Excel / Numbers and check the distribution. They will never be exact, but close.

How you assign weights to your Parse results is up to you. For example, you can assign objects with `createdAt = today` to have a weight of 7; yesterday's to have weight of 6 and so forth.